# Django single-test migration

Tags: django, testing

I have recently implemented a reusable app within the django project I am working on. For the sake of the question, let's call it `reusable_app`. This app also has some unittests that run, however, these tests depend on some basic models declared somewhere next to the tests in a `model.py`.

```
/resuable_app
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py
    /tests
        __init__.py
        tests.py
        /simple_app
            __init__.py
            models.py
```

Now, the models aren't loaded in the database unless I specify the folder in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the testing configuration file. I was wondering if there is another way to achieve this, not having to expose the app in the settings file? I seem to be able to specify the app via `@override_settings`, but the migrations are not ran.

Ex:

```
@override_settings(INSTALLED_APPS=['reusable_app'])
class TestReusableApp(TestCase):
def test_something(self):
     ...
```

If `reusable_app` is not specified in the settings module `INSTALLED_APPS` this still yields a `ProgrammingError`. Am I missing something or is there another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the test runner is setting up the tables *before* you add the app with `@override_settings`.

Normally what I do with reusable apps is to run the tests in the context of an "example" app, with settings that include the app your want to test. Usually works pretty well, as I'm packaging the reusable app separately. Here's an [example](https://github.com/theonion/djes/tree/master/example) of this from a past project of mine.

However, if that's not possible, you might try to override `setUp` in your tests, and call the "migrate" command within that code. For example:

```
from django.core.management import call_command

@override_settings(INSTALLED_APPS=['reusable_app'])
MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        call_command('migrate', 'reusable_app')
```

This is a bit messy, but it might be worth trying. Depending on how things go, you might also have to run [`django.setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.setup).